# Alternative to VS 2010 WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web, browser, chromium

Web browser control of vs2010 had page errors with some web sites I navigated, so I tried Gecko, Chromium browsers and had no luck.

Both Chromium and Gecko the namespace was not found when compiling even if no error on code. The reason may be both Gecko and Chromium uses .Net framework 4.5.2 but vs2010 does not seems support to that even if I installed the .Net framework 4.5.2.

I have to stick to vs2010. Can anyone please point me in right direction to get browser work on vs2010 without script errors?

Answer (score 0):

there is a chrome based browser control [check this](https://cefsharp.github.io/)
but you need earlier version to be compatible with .net4 
I think [this version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/57.0.0)

use it in this way:

```
using CefSharp.WinForms;
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
parent.Controls.Add(browser);
```

Comment: I tried it many times but ended up with this; Install-Package : Unable to read package from path 'cef.redist.x64.3.2987.1601.nupkg'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  CefSharp.WinForms -Version 57.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidDataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackage